# Starting an independent clause with "more," to omit the use of the adverb "specifically"

Tags: adverbs

Would it be incorrect English to do what I noted above? That is, if my sentence looked like this:
[..]; more specifically,[..]

Could I make it look like this:
[..]; more,[..]

Comment: Starting any clause with a conjunction like “more,” or “specifically” defines that clause as dependant on what went before… how could that not prohibit independence?

Either way, "Can you suggest me…" will always be wrong.

The correct uses are either "Can you suggest *to* me…" or just "Can you suggest…".

Does that much make sense?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin the initial part of your comment is useful, but I don't understand from "Either way" onwards. What does "Can you suggest me…" have to do with it?

Comment: As you've accepted an answer, I won't do the extra work preparing another, but it's worth noting that the answer doesn't address your question which asks about *using "more" on its own*. Yes you can - e.g. "I am hungry; more, I'm famished" where *more* is an adverb and is equivalent to "more than that", "additionally" or "further" - but it's not a common usage and risks confusing a reader not familiar with that usage.

Comment: "More" is not a synonym of "specifically", and it's not a conjunction but an adverb serving as a connective adjunct where it modifies the clause that follows it.  It works the same way as "further" or "moreover".

Comment: Chappo thanks for that above and I'd almost think 'from "Either way" onwards' was a mistake I Posted in the wrong thread… I'd happily delete it but that would leave your Comment hung out to dry…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far as I'm aware, but you can omit the 'more', leaving you with something like this:

> I am hungry; specifically, I'm famished.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really? Can you say how that works?

Comment: It is the same as "more specifically",  but less so. "Specifically" is an adverb, more is 'describing' the adverb. One might also say "less specifically", for example.

Comment: Yes, of course. How does that not insist that your clause is dependant?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What would make which clause dependent in what manner?

Comment: How many clauses are there in "I am hungry; specifically, I'm famished." How do they relate to the OQ or to each other?

Comment: It's a compound sentence made of an independent clause, a conjunction (specifically) and another independent clause.